# Code fails to show image - java.io.IOException at Image.createImage

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, midp

I'm trying to create a splash screen using LWUIT. I want a form to load and display text and an imagefor 5 seconds then continue to the next form. I have a code but fails to show the image. The class and the image are stored together int he same package. Instead, it shows an error.

```
java.io.IOException
```

What could be the problem? This is the code

```
 package tungPackage;

 import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
 import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
 import com.sun.lwuit.Image;
 import com.sun.lwuit.Label;
 import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;


 public class photoMidlet extends MIDlet {

 public void startApp() {
    Display.init(this);
      try {
        Form splashscreen = new Form();

        // Label splashText   = new Label("Baldy");
        Image image        = Image.createImage("/splash.png");
        Label pictureLabel = new Label(image);

        splashscreen.addComponent(pictureLabel);
        splashscreen.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Form x = new Form("ERROR");

        String y = ex.toString();

       Label g = new Label(y);

       x.addComponent(g);
       x.show();

    }

 }

 public void pauseApp() {
 }

 public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
 }
 }
```

Comment: What is the exception message displayed?

Comment: its caught then displayed on the another form x as shown in the code.

Comment: you should specify this message in your question

Comment: AFAIU [`Image.createImage(path)`](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Image.html#createImage%28java.lang.String%29) would be expecting the `path` to represent a file path.  Try instead [`Image.createImage(InputStream)`](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Image.html#createImage%28java.io.InputStream%29) with an IS obtained from an URL.

Comment: @ default locale, I've added the exception @Andrew Thompson the file and the code are locted in the same packege. why would I use a URL?

Comment: IOException probably means that jvm is not able to find the file "/splash.png".  Check if you have such a file.  You can also try giving full file path.

Comment: *"why would I use a URL?"*  By run-time, classes and other resource are generally bundled into a Jar.  It is not possible to access Jar entries by File, but they are available by URL formed from something like `this.getClass().getResource("the.thing");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your JAR file using a ZIP utility (e.g. 7-zip) and look in the root of the file. If splash.png isn't in the root of the jar that's your problem!

Place splash.png so it is in the root of the jar.

Comment: This works well. I suggest you check your code, check the case of the files and the packaging in the jar.